# Read/Write files in Python

Tags: python, file, file-io, permissions

I need to make a file readable and writable in python. Currently the file is read-only. I am running on a Windows machine. I run the following code:

```
os.chmod(projectPath, stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IREAD)
```

on a file that needs to be read/write. But when I try to execute the file that needs to be read write, I get the following:

```
ISDEV : fatal error -2200: Could not overwrite file C:\WINDOWS\Temp\STixInstaller\STixInstallShield.ism
```

So obviously, it is not making the file read/write. I then check the file permissions and it is still read-only.

Any ideas why this fails or if there is an easier way to do this I am missing?

Comment: @RestRisiko How can I tell if it is locked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you only need the stat.S_IWRITE mode.
I just ran a test with this code

```
def main():
    path = "C:\\temp\\log.txt"
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
```

And it set a file that was read only to not read only, where as when I ran it with S_IREAD instead, it set it back to read only

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permissions to change the file. Who is the owner of the file? Is it the one who runs the Python script? All these have to be taken into account.

Comment: Its actually run as part of a build script which has full access to the file. I was thinking that perhaps `stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IREAD` does not actually do what I think it does or there is some OS specific thing going on here under Windows.